# sudden,but relatively brief lag spikes over wifi?

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking

Over wireless the network speed is pretty good, but there are times when suddenly it will act very strained for a few seconds, then happily hop back to it's normal speed.

It's not as noticeable web browsing, but when streaming or playing games it happens at the worst times.

If it was only occasionally, I might not mind, but it seems odd to have excellent performance for a few minutes, then have absolutely terrible for a few seconds,then happily continue afterwards.

I can't get ethernet over CAT5e in the room I'm in because of some ISP restriction.
 could this problem be chip specific, and simply replacing the USB adapter would help, or would I need to try to convert the coax into a cat5 for my PC?

Comment: This is the nature of wireless. What you are experiencing is RF pollution. You're options are to build a Faraday cage around your house or use wired connections.

Comment: Use [inSSIDer](http://www.inssider.com/) to analyze the wireless pollution around you.  It may help you find a better wireless channel to use.  The doc that comes included is pretty straight forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check if your ipv6 is disabled. Win 7 tries to connect on ipv6 after regular intervals, when it fails it reverts back to ipv4. Just download and install a patch from microsoft website to disable ipv6 and see if it helps you.

Comment: on the Microsoft website there's a tool that will enable and disable it, but it has a warning that it will slow startup by 5 seconds. is there a particular reason for it to be 5 seconds specifically,and is that harmful?

Comment: This answer is just wrong. it's a wireless channel issue.  See my other comment attached to the question.

Comment: interestingly, it did help. at least, at the time I tried the behavior was completely absent.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually disable the ipv6 without a patch.

Control Panel -> Network and Internet -> Network and Sharing Center

Click on Wireless Network Connection (*Wireless Network Name*)

Click on properties in the lower left corner of the popup.

In the middle of the Wireless Network Connection Properties you can see Internet Protocol Version 6 and 4 in the list.  Uncheck 6.